# How can I include div children in .not() statement

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using .not() in an if statement and currently it doesn't get the children or the div itself. I want to select the parent div (class of mean-container) and all the child elements such as the ul, li and nav.

Here's my Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').on('click', function(event) {
        if (jQuery('div').not('mean-container')) {
            alert('this is meant to slide up');
        }
    });
});
```

Currently, the alert pops up regardless of where I click.. and before the .not() it was:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').on('click', function(event) {
        if (jQuery(this).attr('class') !== 'mean-container' || jQuery(this).attr('class') !== 'meanmenu-reveal') {
            alert('this is meant to slide up');
        }
    });
});
```

but that did the same thing, what's wrong with the code?

the HTML (in un-dynamic form):

```
<div class="header-left-mid mean-container">
    <div class="mean-bar">
        <a style="right: 0px; left: auto; text-align: center; text-indent: 0px; font-size: 18px;" class="meanmenu-reveal meanclose" href="#nav">X</a>
     <nav class="mean-nav">    
          <ul style="display: block;">
              <li class="level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Lorem </span><span class="boder-menu"></span></a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery version: 1.11.0

Comment: use `if (jQuery('div').not('.mean-container')) {`

Comment: Voting to close, because the question turns out to be unclear, and it's attracting only answers guessing to the actual problem. Please try to describe in more detail what you are actually trying to do. Apparently not only are there small syntax errors in the selectors you use, but also there is a flaw in the logic altogether, although your description isn't clear enough to fix this for you. The alert suggests you want to slide something up, so maybe there is a better approach.

Comment: agree with @GolezTrol that the expected behavior and goal has not been clearly defined. this is an `X-Y problem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery('div').not('mean-container')` returns a jQuery object which will always be truthy regardless if element exists or not. Secondary,  it is missing a `dot` but will still return object

A better test would be

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('mean-container'))
```

Edit:

I think what you are looking for is to see if clcik happens on the menu in which case you need to check target of the event

```
jQuery('body').on('click', function(event) {
    if (!jQuery(event.target).closest('.mean-container').length) {
        alert('Click is not on the mean-container');
    }
});
```

Comment: OK...where do you want target of click? Just noticed click is on body...what is goal?

Comment: to close a menu but it wasn't working.. so I changed it to an alert, and then I cna worry about closing a menu

Comment: why do you need to conditional then to close it? Still not clear what behaviors need to be

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this?:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').on('click', 'div:not(.mean-container)', function(event) {
            alert('this is meant to slide up');
    });
});
```

I am using :not selector of css.

Comment: I don't understand this *returned nothing full stop*

Comment: as in no alert popped-up

Comment: You must to explain what do you need exactly. Nobody understand what is that you want to achieve. Otherwise, we should vote to close because unclearly post and too broad answers . Sorry.

Comment: Explain it better next time.